# Unable To Upload Source Code on Arduino UNO(Windows 11)

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude, error, upload

I was trying to upload the source code of a project to the Arduino UNO and this is the error that I keep on receiving.

After I closed and reopened it again, the Port option is gray. I tried everything (installing new drivers, uninstalling it) but nothing works. This board works on my PC (Win 10) but doesn't work on my laptop (Win 11).

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\com3" an error occurred while uploading the sketch.
```

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino UNO or a Chinese clone? If a clone, what USB chip does it have on the board?

Comment: @Majenko It's a Chinese clone with an Atmega328p chip

Comment: That's the MCU. What's the USB chip? Is it an ATMega16UI2 or a CH340G?

Comment: @Majenko It's Atmega16U2.